# Word: White highlight behind text on coloured background

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editing, bug

I can't get rid of the white shading on a title in Word. The background is a picture, so I need to remove it. The rest of the text also had it, but selecting character per character, I could turn it off. But the title does not work.

- Mac user
- Word Version 16.83 (24031120)

Hereby a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please publish online your document (Dropbox etc) for analysis.

Comment: No idea if this works like this: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/d7ya01ek8jh1mgy3wlav7/Proposal-Full-Logo.docx?rlkey=xa7idpumlxtor09pa4swzxsx5&dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer comes from the post
[Where does text format Plus: Pattern: Clear (White) come from?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/where-does-text-format-plus-pattern-clear-white/7dd7ba0f-10b7-4bd7-8fc7-811f767c5e0c).

> - Select the affected text (or all text).
> - In the Paragraph group on the Home tab, click the down arrow on the Border button and click Borders and Shading at the bottom of the menu.
> - Click the Shading tab of the Borders and Shading dialog box.
> - Set the Apply To dropdown set to "Text".
> - Set the Fill dropdown to any color except white or "No Color", and then change it to "No Color". (If you don't do this little dance, the
>   dialog won't do anything!)
> - Leave the Style dropdown set to "Clear".
> - Click OK.

I verified that indeed this manipulation is truly necessary
("this little dance"). There's perhaps some bug in Word that
otherwise won't let you get rid of this shading.

You might define the modified paragraph style as a new style
that doesn't have the white shading, or modifying directly the
"Title" style if it's used in more than one place in the document.

Comment: That does the trick! I hate Word but I love your help ;) Thank you!!

Comment: can I ask you another question? Can I email you maybe, or chat? https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/svdyxidcn03jnv6p2usxh/Proposal-Full-Logo.docx?rlkey=2wdv4jwpz85bpr5jqn3aqz98l&dl=0

Comment: Please ask your question on a separate post and drop me a note here.

Comment: bare with me :) 
https://superuser.com/questions/1837128/word-square-blocks-in-front-of-text-toc