# Word : square blocks in front of text (TOC ?)

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

These square blocks appeared in front of my text in Word, but when I print of PDF, they do not show up. That's good, I don't want them, but why are they there? Is it a preview thing? Can I turn it off? It is going to confuse my client as it is me ;)

[image]

Comment: Poster gave this link for downloading the document : https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/svdyxidcn03jnv6p2usxh/Proposal-Full-Logo.docx?rlkey=2wdv4jwpz85bpr5jqn3aqz98l&dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The squares appear because you have selected `Keep with text` or `Keep lines together`. They are just markers used by word.

[image]

To hide them, click on the `Show/Hide` button

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I am a terrible beginner at Word lay-outing... but learning!

Comment: Specifically, these indicate some special paragraph formatting that deals with line spacing. You may want to start here: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/BasicConceptsWord.htm It is a series of short tutorial pages and does not take much time.